# Can't change ImageButton tooltip or style on GridView fired postback event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, tooltip, imagebutton

Hi I'm having a really strange issue here. I have an ImageButton and Gridview, both of which I create on runtime. The Image button is a seperate control on the webform and is not linked in anyway to the Gridview. What I am trying to achieve is when the user completes the editing of a line in the GridView and clicks on the update row button, I perform a set of calculations on the input entered. If an error is found with the data entered, I then make visible the ImageButton which when clicked displays the error message. The function I am using to make visible or hide the Image button through

picCross.Style.Value = "display: none;"

and

picCross.Style.Value = "display: block;"

gets called on the Page.PreRender function. What I have discovered is that I am able to make changes to the ImageButton (changing the button's tooltip, setting its Style's value ) during a postback not fired by the GridView, such as when the user clicks on a button else where on the web form. If however I try making changes to the Imagebutton during the post back event of the GridView, such as when the user clicks on the edit row or update row button/link. The changes are not saved. What is even more strange  is I do not have such an issue with labels. I can change the text of labels regardless on whether the change was made during the postback fired off by the Gridview control.

I have tried setting the ImageButton's EnableViewState to true and false but neither makes a difference. I have tried the same approach with panels and the same thing occurs, I can't change its properties during a postback caused by the gridview. My GridView has EnableViewState = True

P.S I'm binding the GridView on runtime too. Only my GridView's RowUpdating event fires. The RowUpdated event does not fire. I was hoping to try changing the ImageButton on RowUpdated, not that I think it would have made much of a difference anyway.

Comment: Why don't you use Visibe property of the ImageButton? Maybe you could use a CustomValidator to implement this check and make visible this imagebutton.

Comment: I can't change the visible property of the ImageButton either. Its as though the ImageButton I'm changing during a GridView fired postback event is a cached copy. I can see through a  break point that it is correctly setting the ImageButton property but once the page fully loads the changes are not there. My ImageButtons are external and unrelated to my GridView which is what I find perplexing but yet I can change the property of a label during a GridView post back event with no issues...

Answer (score 0):

You should create the dynamic controls (Gridview and ImageButtons) in the PreInit event.  Init event if you have a Master Page.